# Running from terminal, changes the character encoding! I think. ( UBUNTU )

Tags: php, ubuntu, character-encoding, terminal, command-line-interface

I asked that question,
[Ubuntu Zend Framework cli securityCheck Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756780/ubuntu-zend-framework-cli-securitycheck-error)

and i found the problem. Actually it is not about zendframework. Because it happens doctrine too. And it doesnt happen if i run my web site from browser. The problem is as i wrote before.

> My operating system using utf8
>   character encoding for file names.
>   utf8-encoded file names with the php
>   is run by the terminal gives the
>   error. 'I' is the upper one 'ı' in my
>   language. But php expects to be 'i'.
>   If i change the file names to ASCII in
>   php using iconv , error happens again
>   because it cant find the location of
>   the file at this time.

How can i run php from cli same like through apache.

PLEASE HELP ! ( thank you in advance )

Comment: I don't really understand what is causing the error, are trying to run some php script which is named in utf8 like `$ php sçripté.php`? If you do I'd rather advise to don't, use only ASCII for you filename as it will save your time to debug what's wrong.

Comment: NO, Reading files from php, like scandir functions. That filenames become utf8.  there is more info in my previous question which i gave top of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is: Everytime solve your own things.

Anyway,

My linux locale is UTF-8 so i've changed it to 8859-9 locale setting. There are many place to change locale settings in ubuntu. But the easiest way to change it in /etc/default/locale.

And i am happy, it's working now.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

May be [this package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+package/php5-cli) (or similar) required to run php scripts as cli?